# Change from getElementById to getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Hi i got a script like this:

```
$(".news-button").click(function(){
    var img = document.getElementById('news-image').src;
    if (img.indexOf('news-bt-1.png')!=-1) {
        document.getElementById('news-image').src  = 'img/news-bt-2.png';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('news-image').src = 'img/news-bt-1.png';
    }

});
```

It worked fine but now i want to change **news-image** from id to class so how to change the code above?

Comment: what is the class name?

Comment: @Lucifer i suggested you to use jquery instead of javascript inside the click function because it would reduce the cross platform risk. Check my answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use `getElementsByClassName` and select the first element**, because this method returns a list of Elements which is ordered by the position of the elements in the DOM.

So, given that the element you want to get is the first one that appears in your HTML code with that class, you can do:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("news-image")[0]
```

And if it isn't the first one, you can change the number and select another element:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("news-image")[2] // third element
```

**You can also use `querySelector`** to select the first element that matches the given CSS selector, which is, in my opinion, easier:

```
document.querySelector("img.news-image")
```

Finally, since I see you're **using jQuery** as well, you can use it's selector like this:

```
$("img.news-image")[0]
```

---

Talking about your specific code, **here's the solution** you were looking for:

```
$(".news-button").click(function(){
    var img = $('img.news-image')[0];
    if (img.src.indexOf('news-bt-1.png')!=-1) {
        img.src  = 'img/news-bt-2.png';
    }
    else {
        img.src = 'img/news-bt-1.png';
    }
});
```

Comment: @LuciferLee you're welcome. If my answer solved your question, I suggest you to mark it as correct so that future users with the same problem will find it easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getElementsByClassName instead getElementById

Comment: I did but the script doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use :-

```
document.getElementsByClassName('news-image')[0].src
```

Since getElementsByClassName returns array you need to use index of it.

But as i can see you are using jquery on click event then why you are using javascript inside it instead use jquery inside it will help you in cross-platform

```
$(".news-image").each( function() {
   var img= $(this).attr('src');
 if (img.indexOf('news-bt-1.png')!=-1) {
           $(this).attr('src','img/news-bt-2.png') 
  }else{
  $(this).attr('src','img/news-bt-1.png') 
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(classname)
```

It will get you all the elements matched as an array. So first make sure you got the array, then access the elements like elements[index]

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, just Replace `className` with the actual class name of you tag `img` :

```
$(".news-button").click(function () {
        var img = document.getElementById('news-image').src;
        var img1 = document.getElementsByClassName("className");
        if (img.indexOf('news-bt-1.png') != -1) {
            img1.src = 'img/news-bt-2.png';
        }
        else {
            img1.src = 'img/news-bt-1.png';
        }

    });
```

Comment: hey @LuciferLee, here is full code wht u hv asked for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery as well.

To get source of image:

```
$('.classname').attr('src')
```